# Usar recursos da classe Timer (System.Timers) onera um serviço do Windows?

Tags: c#, .net, services, timer

*Estou precisando fazer uma verificação no banco de dados uma vez por dia*.

Estou pensando em utilizar a classe [`Timer (System.Timers)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx). O recurso contator de tempo irá onerar/travar os outros serviços do sistema?

Esta solução é aconselhável dentro de um *service* Windows?

Sistema: C#, Projeto Windows Service, evento que dispara o *timer*: `OnStart()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não, a classe é feita para o que você deseja. Com ela você vai "assinar um evento" com o sistema operacional e uma sinalização será enviada para sua aplicação quando der o tempo determinado e transferirá o controle para o código determinado por você tão logo quanto seja possível. Portanto ele não fica contando o tempo, não consome processamento enquanto está esperando o evento ocorrer. Ele apenas [observa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/36655/101) um evento externo.

Pode até haver soluções melhores dependo do que você deseja, mas estou confiando que o que você precisa é algo que só o `Timer` resolve. Pode ser que você nem precise de uma aplicação específica para isto. Pode fazer algo mais simples, talvez até um *script* que fique agendado no sistema operacional. Enfim, sem saber exatamente sua necessidade não posso falar de uma solução ideal. Para o que você postou, acho que está respondido.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Prezado bigown!
A ideia é que ao atingir o tempo determinado o serviço verifique se a senha do serviço que ele disponibiliza está expirando. Se sim ele muda a senha automaticamente e envia e-mail avisando da mudança aos interessados.

Creio que você respondeu com precisão o que queria saber, muito obrigado!

Comment: Sem todos os detalhes é claro que é impossível fazer afirmações definitivas mas pode ser que conceitualmente (não necessariamente mais simples ou melhor) poderia ser interessante configurar o servidor para notificar sua aplicação em determinada situação (se o seu DB possuir este recurso) e dispensar o *timer*, assim fica *on-demand* mesmo, ou seja, sua aplicação só é invocada quando realmente é necessário. Mas aí já é outro assunto.