# Automatização da execução de um arquivo .exe

Tags: c#

Preciso que uma aplicação fique executando em background, na bandeja do sistema, 3 vezes ao dia, as 08:00, as 12:00 e as 16:00 ele execute um arquivo .exe.

Comment: Você já tem algum código pronto pra colocar na pergunta?

Comment: Você tem dois caminhos básicos, agendar isto no sistema operacional ou deixar a aplicação rodando (se possível como serviço para "garantir" sua execução é colocar um Timer nela. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30601/101 Me parece que o que você quer é criar uma aplicação que agende a execução de outra aplicação. Se for isto, não faz muito sentido. É melhor agendar no SO a aplicação que deve executar em tempos regulares. Se for outra coisa, explique melhor.

Comment: Se for no Windows, o agendador de tarefas serve exatamente para isso. Foi desenvolvido e evoluiu durante anos levando uma série de questões do SO, provavelmente é a ferramenta mais adequada. Em linux, o crontab é o caminho mais adequado.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a [biblioteca Quartz Enterprise Scheduler .NET](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) para executar tarefas agendadas em uma aplicação, seja em um horário pré-definido ou de tempos em tempos.

> *Quartz.NET is a full-featured, open source job scheduling system that can be used from smallest apps to large scale enterprise systems.*
>
> *It is a pure .NET library written in C# and is a port of very popular open source Java job scheduling framework, Quartz.*

Answer (score 0):

Gosto de usar o [FluentScheduler](https://github.com/jgeurts/FluentScheduler) , como o próprio nome sugere, tem uma escrita fluente.

Com ele você pode escrever algo assim :

```
    using FluentScheduler;

       public class MeuAgendamento : Registry
        {
            public MeuAgendamento()
            {
                Schedule(() => Console.WriteLine("Vou executar todos os dias às 08:00 ")).ToRunEvery(1).Days().At(8, 0);

                Schedule(() => Console.WriteLine("Vou executar todos os dias às 12:00 ")).ToRunEvery(1).Days().At(12, 0);

                Schedule(() => Console.WriteLine("Vou executar todos os dias às 16:00 ")).ToRunEvery(1).Days().At(16, 0);

                Schedule(() => Console.WriteLine("E se quiser posso executar a cada 3 meses, na primeira sexta-feira às 11:47 ")).ToRunEvery(3).Months().OnTheFirst(DayOfWeek.Friday).At(11, 47);

                Schedule(() => MeuMetodo()).ToRunNow().AndEvery(4).Hours();

            }

            private void MeuMetodo()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ou executar um método agora e então cada 4 horas");
            }
        } 

//Depois basta inicializar os agendamentos.
//Se for um serviço do windows essa inicialização pode ser no OnStart do serviço.
//Se for um webSite, essa inicialização pode ocorrer no Application_Start.
class static Main (string[] args)
{
    TaskManager.Initialize(new MeuAgendamento()); 
}
```

Você pode baixá-lo pelo Nuget.