# Tarefas agendadas na web

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, aplicação-web, agendamento

No Inbox do Google permite a criação de lembretes e permite adiar os mesmos pra uma certa data e horário. O lembrete é então tirado da tela principal e quando chega essa exata data e horário ele volta pra la.

Dessa forma, o sistema *agenda* uma tarefa pra uma data e horário e quando chega essa data e horário ele executa o que foi agendado.

Eu achava que isso seria impossível na web pela seguinte razão: pelo que eu sei uma aplicação hospedada num servidor web (seja um site, uma API, ou outra coisa) só executa alguma coisa quando existe uma requisição. Dessa forma, a aplicação espera uma requisição, quando ela recebe ela executa o que foi pedido e volta a ficar ociosa.

Nesse caso que eu citei do Inbox não é o que acontece. Chega a data e horário agendados e o sistema realiza uma tarefa sem precisar de uma requisição pra isso. Também não é dizer que precise de *client* conectado, porque pelo que eu percebi acho que sem nenhum *client* conectado ele também faz.

Como posso fazer esse tipo de coisa num ambiente ASP.NET? Não digo nem com IIS necessariamente, porque agora com o ASP.NET 5 as opções de hospedagem vão aumentar bastante. Existe como ter esse recurso da aplicação executar uma determinada tarefa agendada sem depender de requisições? Se existe, como isso funciona?

Comment: Você pode ter um programa rodando no servidor que executa as tarefas. Este programa pode rodar baseado em um período de tempo ou em algum evento. Eu uso 2 soluções para este fim, o WebJob da azure e o HangFire. O webjobs permite que você rode um executável baseado em um tempo ou evento em queue ou blob. O Hangfire é mais limitado mas funciona muito bem para eventos disparados pelo seu site (embora ele funcione fora do asp.net também).

Comment: @Leo o Hangfire funciona tranquilamente nas vm do azure ? ou há incompatibilidade por causa do webjobs ? preciso de um gerenciador de background, pensei no webjobs mesmo, por usar azure, mas o Hangfire parece mais flexivel

Comment: @Rod, uso ele a mais de 6 meses em um website na azure e funciona 100%, nunca deu problema nenhum. Vai sem medo :D

Comment: @Rod, nunca usei o Hangfire, então não sei dizer se tudo que ele oferece o Web Jobs também oferece. Mas você tem outra opção também que são os cloud services. Neles você constroi aplicações N-tier sendo que você pode adicionar camadas de processamento em plano de fundo usando as worker roles e camadas contendo websites ou web apis com as web roles. Pesquise um pouco sobre isso, talvez te ajude.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essencialmente da mesma forma que você faria em uma tarefa não *web*. É igual ao que você faz no seu computador. Pode ser o agendador de tarefas do Windows, o [`cron`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2818/101) existente em distribuições Linux e assemelhados, ou outro software agendador qualquer. A aplicação que roda no servidor é uma aplicação como outra qualquer.

## Solução simples

Acho que o ideal é criar uma aplicação separada do resto da aplicação *web* propriamente dita. Nela você coloca o que precisa ser executado em *background* em tempos regulares e o que só serve ao que será executado no servidor. Em tese pode usar qualquer tecnologia para isto. Não precisa necessariamente estar ligado ao ASP.Net, mesmo que esta seja a tecnologia que você use no resto da solução. Assim não mistura com a aplicação que conversa diretamente com o cliente. Em alguns casos isso pode dar mais poder evitando problemas de segurança. Imagine essa aplicação que roda agendada precisa de privilégio elevado e está junto com o que o servidor HTTP executa. Perigoso, não?

## Soluções prontas

Claro que estes agendadores precisam de permissão para seu uso. Nem toda hospedagem tem isto à disposição.

- No [artigo do Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) tem algumas formas de fazer isto via código.
- Eu mesmo [já respondi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30604/101) algo relacionado à isto.
- Existem [várias (1)](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) [bibliotecas (2)](http://taskscheduleraspnet.codeplex.com/) [específicas (3)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2407/A-New-Task-Scheduler-Class-Library-for-NET) para isto.
- A [SE usa ou usava algo assim](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/).
- [Artigo na MSDN Magazine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2005/march/scheduling-asp-net-code-to-run-using-web-and-windows-services?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).
- A lista pode ir longe.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md)

Comment: Obrigado @bigown, isso que tem no artigo do Scott Hanselman é o que eu precisava mesmo, além disso finalmente descobri a utilidade da Worker Role no Azure. Isso que você falou de criar uma aplicação separada da aplicação web é equivalente a separação Worker Role e Web Role do Cloud Services do Azure?

Comment: Não conheço em detalhes essa tecnologia então não posso fazer uma avaliação. Dá para dizer que de certa forma sim, pelo menos o objetivo é o mesmo mas a forma de fazer e a capacidade de cada um é bem diferente. O que eu falei é fazer algo trivial independente de tecnologia. A não ser que tenha algum motivo para usar outra coisa é sempre o caminho que eu sigo.