# Por onde começar um sistema que realiza uma tarefa de hora em hora

Tags: java

Estou um pouco confuso, por onde posso começar um sistema que realiza uma tarefa a cada hora? Tem algum framework?

O sistema será desktop e irá rodar em um servidor Windows Server 2003. A ideia é que a cada 1 hora o sistema faça uma busca no banco de dados e com os dados retornados gerar um arquivo `xml` para que minha aplicação web ler esse `xml` e carregar os dados em uma `DataTable`

Comment: Acho que eu consegui algo, porém só me tirem uma dúvida.
`public static final long TEMPO = (1000 * 60 *60 );` isso dá igual a 1 hora?

Comment: Isso é uma hora em milissegundos.

Comment: Mas por que você não cria um programa que faz a tarefa uma vez, e agenda no servidor para que seja executado de hora em hora? Ver http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41275/tarefas-agendadas-na-web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há várias formas de resolver este problema, considerando um sistema 100% *back end*.

## Use o agendador do sistema

O Windows possui um Agendador de Tarefas bastante flexível e poderoso. Talvez seja mais simples configurá-lo para chamar seu programa via linha de comando em horários agendados.

## Usando o agendador do Java

Se quiser fazer o agendamento via Java mesmo, use uma classe da API que já faz isso para você. Não precisa fazer conta de milissegundos, segundos, minutos e horas.

Veja, por exemplo, a documentação do [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). Lá tem tudo e até um exemplo funcional, o qual adaptei no código abaixo:

```
public class BeeperControl {

    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    public void beepForAnHour() {

        //beep task
        final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("beep");
            }
        };

        //beep each hour
        final ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 0, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS);

        //cancel beep task
        final Runnable canceler = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                beeperHandle.cancel(false);
            }
        };

        //stop beep after 1 day
        scheduler.schedule(canceler, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BeeperControl().beepForAnHour();
    }

}
```

Vamos analisar o código acima:

1. A linha `ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)` chama um método *factory* para criar um *executador de serviços agendados* (tradução do nome da classe).
2. Dentro do método `beepForAnHour`, o primeiro bloco declara uma implementação de `Runnable` chamada `beeper`. Trata-se da mesma API que implementa *threads*. Esta, especificamente, imprime `beep` no console.
3. O comando `scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 0, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS)` é o mais interessante aqui. Ele agenda a execução do nosso *bipador* (*beeper*) a intervalos regulares de uma hora (parâmetros 3 e 4), sendo que a primeira execução é imediata (segundo parâmetro).
4. O trecho seguinte cria outro `Runnable` chamado `canceler`. Este será responsável, quando executado, por cancelar o agendamento periódico feito anteriormente.
5. O comando `scheduler.schedule(canceler, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS);` agenda uma única execução do nosso `canceler` para exatamente um dia depois. Então, no dia seguinte, o `beep` vai parar.

## Cenário crítico

No caso de tarefas agendadas que são críticas para o negócio, por ser interessante replicar o programa em vários servidores. Caso um deles falhe, os demais conseguirão executar a rotina crítica. Entretanto, se o processamento for pesado, não é conveniente que ele execute de forma redundante, isto é, executa várias vezes nesses diferentes servidores.

Para casos assim, existem bibliotecas de agendamento como o [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) que possuem configurações específicas para *clusters* de servidores. Dessa forma, você pode fazer o *deploy* da aplicação em diversos servidores e, neste exemplo, o Quartz vai gerenciar a execução, garantindo que sua tarefa será executada devidamente uma vez.

Mesmo com um único servidor, o Quartz consegue garantir que uma execução perdida quando o servidor está em manutenção será retomada assim que o servidor estiver disponível.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, esclareceu bastante minha dúvida. Agora só tenho que analisar qual das opções se aplica melhor em meu caso.