# Como atualizar uma JLabel periodicamente?

Tags: java, swing

Gostaria de saber como ficar atualizando periodicamente um `Jlabel`, visto que esse label depende de outro método. No caso seria o `lblNewLabel_1`.

```
public class MenuGFinancas extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane1;
    private String nome;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MenuGFinancas frame = new MenuGFinancas("Teste");
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public MenuGFinancas(String nome) {

        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\admin\\Documents\\Java         Project PP\\Imagens\\icone_prestacao_contas.jpg");

        setTitle("GFinancas Beta");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 770, 427);
        setIconImage(image.getImage());
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        contentPane1 = new JPanel();
        contentPane1.setForeground(new Color(152, 251, 152));
        contentPane1.setOpaque(true);
        contentPane1.setBackground(new Color(255, 69, 0));
        contentPane1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane1);
        contentPane1.setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);

        MenuBar menu = new MenuBar();
        menu.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        menu.setBounds(0, 0, 764, 22);
        contentPane1.add(menu);
        menu.setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Olá " +nome);
        lblNewLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Trajan Pro", Font.BOLD, 14));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(0, 22, 764, 34);
        contentPane1.add(lblNewLabel);

        JLabel lblContaCorrente = new JLabel("Conta Corrente");
        lblContaCorrente.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);
        lblContaCorrente.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18));
        lblContaCorrente.setBounds(36, 113, 174, 22);
        contentPane1.add(lblContaCorrente);

        JLabel lblSaldo = new JLabel("Saldo: ");
        lblSaldo.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lblSaldo.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        lblSaldo.setBounds(36, 165, 61, 14);
        contentPane1.add(lblSaldo);

        MostraSaldo mostraSaldo = new MostraSaldo();
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        String saldo = String.valueOf(df.format(mostraSaldo.PegaSaldo()));
        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel(saldo);
        lblNewLabel_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(107, 165, 68, 14);
        contentPane1.add(lblNewLabel_1);



        JLabel label = new JLabel("");
        label.setBackground(new Color(153, 255, 51));
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\admin\\Documents\\Java Project PP\\Imagens\\back.png"));
        label.setBounds(0, 0, 764, 399);
        contentPane1.add(label);
        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Não amigo, esse label recebe um valor do Banco de Dados, queria que ele ficasse atualizando, por exemplo, de 15 em 15seg, pra caso algum valor seja adicionado ao Banco, o valor aparecesse nesse label. Não sei se estou falando algo sem sentido, sou novato, mas a priori minha ideia  foi essa.

Comment: Entendi, acho que [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/67240/4808) do utluiz pode ajudar.

Comment: Para atualizar acho que é `lblNewLabel_1.repaint();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando trabalhando com `Swing` é mais recomendado usar [`javax.swing.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) do que [`java.util.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html), isto por que todos os *timers* do `Swing` compartilham a mesma *thread* já existente para este propósito e tal *thread* está na [*event dispatch thread*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) .

Para implementar é bem simples, basta implementar a *interface* [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) que possui apenas um método, `actionPerformed`. É ele que irá executar quando o tempo configurado (*delay*) acabar.

Um exemplo de *timer* para atualizar sua UI seria assim:

```
private class TimerToLabel implements ActionListener {

    private Timer timer;
    private final JLabel label;
    private final int delay;

    public TimerToLabel(final int delay, final JLabel label) {
        this.delay = delay;
        this.label = label;
    }

    public void init() {
        timer = new Timer(delay, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
        // faça aqui sua consulta
        label.setText("" + Math.random());
        label.updateUI();
    }

}
```

Considerando o seu *label*, `lblNewLabel_1`, basta incluir isto:

```
// configurado para 1 segundo, configure conforme sua necessidade (em milisegundos)
final TimerToLabel timer = new TimerToLabel(1000, lblNewLabel_1);
timer.init();
```

Este é um exemplo dele rodando:

[image: Timer rodando]

Veja mais em [Como Usar Temporizadores com Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).